# Discord bot is not running with uptime robot and repl.it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to make my own discord bot which should be online without my pc running, so I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gqurhm2QxA0

It all worked fine and yesterday my bot was running and the whole time even without the repl.it website being online. I thought my discord bot was staying online forever.
But today he is not online, even if I restart my repl.it project. Here is my code for index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new discord.Client({intents:["GUILDS","GUILD_MESSAGES"]});
var bump_timeout = true;
app.listen(3000,()=>{
  console.log("bot is online");
});

app.get("/",(req, res) =>{
  res.send("hello world uwu");
});
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.content === "!d bump" && bump_timeout==true){
    bump_timeout = false;
    message.channel.send("you got 100 coins!");
    setTimeout(bump_switchtimeout, 5000);
  }
})

function bump_switchtimeout(){
  bump_timeout = true;
}

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log("bot is ready");
})


client.login(*here is the token*);
```

I hope you can find out why the bot doesn't get online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repl.it only has a certain amount of time it can keep your project online, and once it passes that threshold it won't stay online anymore. It also has to do with the fact that repl.it only keeps your project online if theres active use of it (eg with a website, people are  visitng said website). Nothing to do with your code.
Try Heroku, which is free, or other paid hosting services  https://www.heroku.com/
https://plox.host/discordbot-hosting

Comment: I am using uptime robot to make it stay online forever and also i have tried heroku with github but it didnt worked because i couldnt connect it with github because there was a bug.

Comment: theres a max time that repl.it stays online to prevent people from doing this. try heroku again, or look for some free discord bot hosters. there are some good ones if you just google it, but they do have not 24/7 uptime etc. because thats paid services features

Comment: So when i have heroku the bot is online 24//? Because there was a video which said it would not be online 24/7.